# multiple instances of superclass member attribute

Tags: kotlin

I have an abstract stub class that needs to be subclasses to add spring annotations.

```
abstract class ConsumerStub<TYPE>{

    val receivedMessages: MutableMap<String, TYPE> = ConcurrentHashMap()

    open fun processMessage(@Payload payload: TYPE, record: ConsumerRecord<String, *>) {
        this.receivedMessages[record.key()] = payload
    }

    fun receivedMessageWithKey(key: String): Boolean = this.receivedMessages.contains(key)

    fun receivedMessageWithKeyCallable(key: String): Callable<Boolean> = Callable { receivedMessageWithKey(key) }

    fun getReceiveMessageWithKey(key: String): TYPE? = this.receivedMessages[key]

    fun reset() {
        this.receivedMessages.clear()
    }
}
```

for example:

```
open class WorkflowRequestConsumerStub: ConsumerStub<InternalWorkflowRequest>() {

    @KafkaListener(
        id = "xyzRequestConsumerStub",
        topics = ["abc-workflow-requests"]
    )
    override fun processMessage(
        @Payload payload: InternalWorkflowRequest,
        record: ConsumerRecord<String, *>
    ) {
        super.processMessage(payload, record)
    }

}
```

I am seeing some really weird behaviour with the receivedMessages. 
After some debugging I realised there seem to be 2 instances of receivedMessages.

stub.reset() throws a null pointer exception

after changing the code to initialize receivedMessages in reset(), processMessage() and receivedMessageWithKey() are seeing 2 different receivedMessages with different objectIds.

what's going on? In java the subclass should have access to any protected members in the super, so I assume the same applies to kotlin.

UPDATE: this works as expected when defining receivedMessages abstract and override in the implementations. That really sucks if this is how it should be done in kotlin. In this case there is no need for the implementation to care about the map.

Comment: If you're seeing 2 different instances of `receivedMessages` that most likely means that you have 2 different instances of a `ConsumerStub` subclass.

Comment: In that case they should be both initialised to concurrenthashmap. In some cases it's null. Unless spring is doing some reflection magic with the bean

Comment: Nothing in the code you show should lead to such problems. Try creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could be an issue of how kotlin generated binaries work with spring proxying. This kind of setup works fine in java+spring.

using an abstract receivedMessages solved the problem. but it's a bad solution